# Stencil.js newE2EPage Styles

Tags: javascript, jestjs, stenciljs

How can we set global styles for Stencil.js newE2EPage.

newE2EPage seems to have a `addStyleTag` method.  Is this a method we can use to set styles and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `page.addStyleTag` which actually comes from puppeteer (see https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=master&show=api-pageaddstyletagoptions).

```
describe('Some Page', () => {
  let page: E2EPage;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await newE2EPage({ html: '<my-comp />' });
    await page.addStyleUrl('/build/app.css'); // replace "app" with your namespace
  });
});
```

Comment: I actually tested this and it did not work .. tried many combinations of this and I'm sure I've got the file location right.  Correct answer is supplied below.

Comment: It does work, however your page won't wait for the network to be idle (i. e. it won't wait for the script to finish loading).

Comment: I did use await page.waitForChanges(); after the addStyleUrl which I believed made it wait for the script to reload.  However, this did not happen.  As a result the approach basically does not work.  Note, I also tried setStyleUrl beforehand after which I did setContent and waitForChanges, but this did not work either.

Comment: `waitForChanges` won't work for that. It's not very straightforward to implement (easiest afaik is to do a fake `window.location` change and then wait for the network to be idle). Instead, you could also use `await page.addStyleTag({ content: fs.readFile('/path/to/app.css') })` (which would inline the css).

Answer (score 0):

I tried page.addStyleUrl(... and it did not work.  Instead I found the only way was to modify the html I'm loading to include the stylesheet.

The correct line specifically for Stenciljs E2E test is:

```
const page = await newE2EPage(
  {html:
    `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/your-project.css"></head>
     <body><your-component></your-component></body>`
  });
```

I've tested that it loads correctly from the build directory.  I have attempted loading locally but that did not work. However, I have not done a comprehensive test to determine what other locations can work.